# How to recognize arabic cultutre in c#

Tags: c#, speech-recognition, culture

I am developing software to recognize Arabic language but my application is not able to recognize Arabic. 
I am using the following code to recognize the cultures installed in system, but it’s giving only 'en-US' and 'en-GB', although i have installed Arabic language in my windows 7

```
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("ar-SA");


foreach (RecognizerInfo config in SpeechRecognitionEngine.InstalledRecognizers())
            {
                if (config.Culture.ToString() == preferredCulture)
                {
                    speechRecognitionEngine = new SpeechRecognitionEngine(config);
                    break;
                }
            }
```

My question is how to add Arabic culture in the application without changing the windows language from English to Arabic; I want to retain windows language to English as it is commonly understood.

Comment: What your code is telling you is that you haven't installed a language recognizer for Arabic.  Which is no great mystery, Microsoft doesn't have one.  You'll need to go shopping.  Random [google hit](http://www.sakhr.com/tts.aspx).

Comment: Random google hit is for the Server recognizer, not the desktop recognizer.  They're not compatible.  Be warned.

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft doesn't ship an Arabic SR engine with *any* Windows release.  As far as I know, there is no SAPI-compatible Arabic SR engine available.  Sorry.

Comment: give any suggest to complete this project.

Comment: @UmairNoor - I don't really have any suggestions.  As far as I can tell, there's exactly *one* [Arabic SR engine](http://sakhrusa.com/arabic-speech-recognition-and-arabic-TTS.html), but it's clearly proprietary and, most likely, expensive.  (If they don't list a price, you can't afford it.)